# Interrupt a line in Chart.js lines

Tags: charts, chart.js

I've a weird situation in chart.js, see the picture
[image]

Basically a dataset with 4 date and 4 numbers. All 4 numbers value are 1 (doesnt matter).
But actually the real data need to show just 2 intervals (1/1/2020 -> 2/2/2020) and (3/4/2021->6/6/2021). Basically without the segment in the middle.

In this case there is no way Chart.js would be able to understand to not drawn that segment, all values are 1 in all 4 different dates.

So the only solution in my mind is to sub divide all the intervals so I can place a NaN in the middle and use something like stepped:true for the line. But with a lot of data I basically double the numbers of dates making the graph more confusing.

So the question is.. Is there any way to specify for given point if it's a start or an end ?
Or maybe there is a better approach instead of a single line dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide code so we can create an answer that is based upon that easier, please

Answer (score 0):

Just pass 2 datasets:

```js
const labels = Utils.months({count: 7});
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 80],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    tension: 0.1
  },{
    label: 'My 2nd Dataset',
    data: [null, null, null, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 40, 192)',
    tension: 0.1
  }]
};
```

If You pass objects instead of arrays as data, then you do not even have to pad with nulls